# Efficient solution to find object of another object

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have class with telephone subscribers, and second class with phones numbers. One subscriber might have few phone number, but one number phone might be associated with only one subscriber. In main system I see all calls of all subscribers. Is there any easier and faster way to find the owner of phone number than check each of subscribers in loop?

```
public class Subscribers{
int clientID;
string name="";
string surname="";
string address="";
List<Phones> allPhones= new List<Phones>;
}

public class Phones{
string number="";
}
```

Comment: The “efficient solution” is called a *database*.

Comment: My wife and I share a phone number (the last landline on Earth). Why can't two subscribers have the same phone? Your model does not restrict it. If a `Phones.SubscriberID` was implemented then it would. Though you would still be able to have an instance of the same number being owned by two subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq this is fairly simple.

```
public IEnumerable<Subscribers> FindSubscriber(
      IEnumerable<Subscribers> subscribers, string phoneNumber)
{
   return 
      from subscriber in subscribers
      where subscriber.allPhones.Any(p => p.number == phoneNumber)
      select subscriber; 
}
```

This will return a list of `Subscribers` which have this phonenumber.

Offtopic but important: Change the naming. Subscribers implies a list of Subscriber, but it isn't. This makes even this small piece of code not as readable as you would wish. See how confusing this method parameters looks:

`IEnumerable<Subscribers> subscribers`

This simple change would help other readers of your code big time:

`IEnumerable<Subscriber> subscribers`